# String format putting leading 0 on the wrong side

Tags: python, string-formatting

So I'm trying to make a function that converts middle-endian date to  ISO 8601.
The "convert" code works as I want it to work but my String Format isnt printing how im wanting it to print.
Heres my Code:

```
def conv_to_iso():
while True:
    try:
        date = input("Date: ")
        Month, Day, Year = date.replace(",", " ").split()
        print(f"{Year}-{M.index(Month)+1:02}-{Day:02}")

    except (EOFError, ValueError):
        print("")
        break
```

So let's say my input is: September 8, 2004

I want the function to print: 2004-09-08

But the function prints this: 2004-09-80

Hope someone can help me with that

Comment: Out of interest, why are you writing such a function and not using the facilities provided by the `datetime` module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior?

Comment: Im doing CS50 python rn and its one of my assignments and till now ive only learned how to use: Conditionals, Loops and Exceptions and i think i should only use what i learned so far to do the assignments

Comment: Hint: what type do you want `Day` to be? What type is it?

Comment: AHHH its type: str but i want it to be type:int, changed it to int(Day):02 and it works now. Thank you